# Adding a required field to a text input through JS?

Tags: javascript

I am making a 'TO DO' list which takes a task that has been inputted by the user and displays it in a list.

I am trying to set the input for the task to be 'required' so that the user can't submit an 'Empty' task.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
    <button class="btn" onclick="createToDo()">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="window.location.reload()">
        Clear List
    </button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function createToDo() {
    var input = document.getElementById("task").value;
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var remove = document.createElement("button");
  
    remove.classList.add("remove");
    remove.innerHTML = "Complete";
    remove.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) =>
        target.parentElement.remove()
    );
  
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.appendChild(remove);
}
```

I have tried to add it directly to the HTML but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What do you need to do?" required/>
```

I have also tried to inject it through JS, but this doesn't seem to work either:

```
const taskInput = document.getElementById("task");
taskInput.setAttribute("required");
```

I understand that when I click the submit it runs the function to create the list, so I'm not sure if there is something that I have to change within the function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wished to use the standard [Client-side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), you need to use a `<form>` element and rely on its submit event instead of binding the handler to the click event of a `<button type="button">`.

Here in this demo I used the `required` attribute for `<input>` and called the `createToDo` when the `submit` event triggers on the parent form.

For the sake of records, a button is by default `type="submit"` .. here I just stressed out explictely

```js
function createToDo() {
  var input = document.getElementById("task").value;
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var remove = document.createElement("button");

  remove.classList.add("remove");
  remove.innerHTML = "Complete";
  remove.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.target.parentElement.remove()
  });

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(remove);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();createToDo();">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What do you need to do?" required />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="window.location.reload()">Clear List</button>
  </div>
</form>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so well! its really helped me understand.

it works just as I want it to

Answer (score 1):

`required` only works if you try to submit a `<form>` without the field being filled.

html

```
<div>
    <form id="myform">
    
    <input type="text" id="task" required placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
     <button class="btn" onclick="window.location.reload()">
        Clear List
    </button>
    </form>
    
</div>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("#myform").addEventListener("submit", (e) => submitForm(e))

function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    // your todolist code here
}
```

Comment: I would remove anonymous function callback definition on adding event listener, because it's unnecessary and makes it harder to later remove the event listener, but overall this is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can short circuit return in `createToDo` when the input don't match specific constraints, e.g. when it is empty:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("task").value;
if (!input) return;
```

A potential alternative is to wrap all the controls in a `<form>` element to let the browser check, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Wrapping the controls in a form does bring up the 'please fill in this field', however, it still creates the list.

I also used the suggested JS but this immediately gets rid of the list after pressing submit.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a form and the submit event it will trigger the required.

Here is a full version using event listeners and delegation

I removed the reload and clear the list instead.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const input = document.getElementById("task");
  const list = document.getElementById("list");
  const form = document.getElementById("todoForm");
  const clear = document.getElementById("clear");
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission;
    let task = input.value.trim();
    if (task === "") return;
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    var remove = document.createElement("button");
    remove.classList.add("remove");
    remove.innerHTML = "Complete";
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task));
    li.appendChild(remove);
    list.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
  });
  clear.addEventListener("click",() => list.innerHTML = "");
  list.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => 
    target.matches(".remove") && target.closest("li").remove()
  );

})
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="What do you need to do?" required/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="clear">
        Clear List
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `required` attribute in HTML is used for form validation, and it works when the input is inside a `<form>` element and you are trying to submit that form.

OR

You can add a validation check within the `createToDo()` function.

```
function createToDo() {
    var input = document.getElementById("task").value.trim();
    if (input !== "") {
        var ul = document.getElementById("list");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var remove = document.createElement("button");

        remove.classList.add("remove");
        remove.innerHTML = "Complete";
        remove.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) =>
            target.parentElement.remove()
        );

        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(remove);
        document.getElementById("task").value = ""; 
    } else {
        alert("Please enter a task!");
    }
}
```